# Powershell script to extract and delete a particular line from a set of similar instances in a file

Tags: powershell

I have one text file as below :

```
[groups]
grp = john, perk, honda, choco, dough
devops = john, honda, perk

[repository:/]
@devops = r
john = rw
honda = r
dough = r

[demo:/]
@grp = r
dough = rw
```

Here I want to remove a string based on the first word search i.e. I want to remove "dough = rw" line from demo ([demo:/] ) block. It should not remove dough from repository( [repository:/] )block.

The Result should look like this :

```
[groups]
grp = john, perk, honda, choco, dough
devops = john, honda, perk

[repository:/]
@devops = r
john = rw
honda = r
dough = r

[demo:/]
@grp = r
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/20/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file/) posting. They are handling ini files, and your file has a similar structure.